# How to associate magento category ID with a custom name(code) of category provided in xml/csv by supplier?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I can not figure out how to assign/associate

**the standard category id provided with magento**

and

**the id/code provided in csv/xml file by the supplier**

E.g.

I have from my supplier this stylesheet with cca. 900 categories in this format: (there are 4 categories and each contians the code and the name)

```
HIER01 HIER01NAME  HIER02 HIER02NAME HIER03 HIER03NAME HIER04    HIER04NAME
35     AUDIO-VIDEO 35TV   TV         35TVPL FLAT       35TVPL10  FLAT 10 “
```

My question is how can I assign the supplier id for audio video category, which is in this case 35, with my id in magento which is 5.

How can I do such a thing?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Btw. I am running 1.5 version of Magento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write some shell scripts that transform the CSV provided by your supplier into the format expected by your own system (in this case, Magento).